# How to slide left and right On click of button for <li>

Tags: html, jquery, css, button, show-hide

I have list of 12 li want them to list in a row when user click on the Left or the right button on both ends of the li would want the names to slide accordingly.
*Need to align the Button, li, Button in same row
*hide some li and show them on click slide

```
<button id="left-button">swipe left </button>

  <ul class="tabs in">
            <li class=internal>India</li>
            <li class=internal>Malaysia</li>
            <li class=internal>Singapore</li>
            <li class=internal>Indonesia</li>
            <li class=internal>Greenland</li>
            <li class=internal>Australia</li>
            <li class=internal>Srilanka</li>          
            <li class=internal>Africa</li>          
            <li class=internal>Europe</li>
            <li class=internal>Paris</li>
            <li class=internal>Germany</li>
            <li class=internal>USA</li>
        </ul>
<button id="right-button">
    swipe right
  </button>
```

[image: rendered output]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This is the code i am rendering